# is not a function occurs when i try to import node module when using require/ =new

Tags: javascript, node.js

This seems incredibly straight forward but for some reason i can't see what the issue is, im trying to import a node module which i've installed, like below

```
const Y18n = require('y18n')
const i18n = new Y18n()
```

However i get the following error:

> i18n.__ is not a function

Why does this method of import not seem to work, it works for other node modules? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try `console.log(Y18n);`? https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: yeah same thing.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. **Remove line 2. Replace it with `console.log(Y18n)`.** See what the module actually exports. Why are *you* asking *us* to make a wild guess for you?

Comment: Where are you getting that syntax for using `y18n`? Looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/yargs/y18n) briefly that doesn't look how it's initialized. Try `const __ = require("y18n")().__;` instead of your require

Comment: `Y18n` in this case is not a constructor. It is a function expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you did not use `y18n` correctly, have you checked the [README](https://github.com/yargs/y18n)?

```js
const __ = require('y18n')().__;
console.log(__('my awesome string %s', 'foo')); // my awesome string foo
```

> ### *`y18n.__(str, arg, arg, arg)`*
>
> *Print a localized string, `%s` will be replaced with `arg`s.*
>
> *This function can also be used as a tag for a template literal. You can use it like this: `` __`hello ${'world'}` `` . This will be equivalent to `__('hello %s', 'world')`.*